# Try and catch with popup message

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch

I am using Try and catch to capture the popup message when there is any invalid username or password.
however, the code only works with the correct login details, when the popup appears with the error, it is throwing an error.... Error screenshot is attached below

[image: Code Screenshot]

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: where is '{' for If condition inside catch block? Is this typo?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the line from

```
catch(NoSuchElementException e)
```

to

```
catch(UnhandledAlertException e)
```

It may works.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Alternatively, if you want to take alert text add DesiredCapabilities

```
 DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
    d = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Then you can handle it by

```
try {
    click(myButton);
} catch (UnhandledAlertException f) {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);
        alert.accept();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```